# RegEx in Sitemap.xml: How do I delete node if descendant node file type is not html?

Tags: regex, xml, sitemap

I have a sitemap generated by a help authoring tool. It lists EVERY file in the help system. I want ONLY the html/htm files. The structure looks like this:

```
<url>
    <loc>https://help.website.com/welcome.htm</loc>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>https://help.website.com/Images/prettyButterfly.png</loc>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>https://help.website.com/Resources/Stylesheets/master.css</loc>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>https://help.website.com/Resources/Scripts/init.js</loc>
</url>
<url>
    <loc>https://help.website.com/gettingStarted/firstSteps.html</loc>
</url>
```

What regex can I use to strip out the nodes (from `<url>` to `</url>`) that do not contain descendant html or htm nodes? I'm planning on using Notepad++ to do the search.

I'm not a great regex-er and I've tried various things to no avail, I could really use some expert help here. Thanks SO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following expression:

```
(<url>\s*<loc>[^<]*\.html?<\/loc>\s*<\/url>)|<url>\s*<loc>[^<]*<\/loc>\s*<\/url>\n?
```

And replace each match with the first capturing group, `\1`.

**Explanation:**

- `(<url>\s*<loc>[^<]*\.html?<\/loc>\s*<\/url>)` - Capturing group to match `<url>` nodes that have a single `<loc>` node ending in either `.html` or `.htm`
- `|` - Alternation.. or:
- `<url>\s*<loc>[^<]*<\/loc>\s*<\/url>` - Match the other `<url>` nodes

In other words, this matches each `<url>` node that contain a single `<loc>` node and replaces each node with the first capturing group. Since only node with HTML/HTM extensions are captured, the other nodes are removed.